# Get past 5 minutes timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript

suppose if time now is 13:36:22 , I want array of past 5 minutes like this

```
2019-05-07T13:36:00+0530
2019-05-07T13:35:00+0530
2019-05-07T13:34:00+0530
2019-05-07T13:33:00+0530
2019-05-07T13:32:00+0530
```

I tried something like below to get past 5 minutes by , but dont know how to remove seconds and to get to that format

```
   var now = new Date();
  now.setSeconds(0);
    var last1 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*60));
     var last2 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*120));

var arr = [last1,last2,..and so on];
```

but its also returning some seconds like `Tue May 07 2019 13:40:57` , I want to remove seconds and also am looking for this format

```
2019-05-07T13:32:00+0530
```

Comment: what have you tried? like set the second to 0 as you describe?

Comment: I have no idea how to remove the seconds , I tried to get past 5 minutes though , with 60 , 120 , 180.Since I donno how to remove only i posted in stackoverflow , else why am gonna post ?

Comment: not even see the document is pretty clear a *do not show any research effort* imho. Whether you solve another question is irrelevant.

Comment: It's important to do thorough research before posting a question on SO. If you look at [MDN's `Date` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you'll find a `setSeconds` method.

Comment: yupe thank you setseconds is working

Comment: now finally , how do i get this format , T13:32:00+0530 , I dont know that name to search in google

Answer (score 0):

You should construct the format yourself, unless you want to use an external library.

First define your timezone `offset` so you can add it to UTC timestamp returned by `Date.now()`. Then set `s` and `ms` to `0` and build your desired date format. Also added the leading `0` for month, day and so on, which is removed by `slice` when the number is already double digits.

```js
let offset = 5.5;
let now = Date.now() + offset*60*60*1000;
date = new Date(now);
date.setSeconds(0, 0);

let timezone = Math.floor(offset) === offset ? 
  "0" + offset + "00" :
  "0" + Math.floor(offset) + "30"

dateString = date.getFullYear() +"-"+ 
  ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"-"+ 
  ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +"T"+ 
  ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) +":"+ 
  ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +":"+ 
  ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) +"+"+
  timezone;
      
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: what is offset 5.5 ?

Comment: Your timezone offset (+0530)